# what could cause 'Read timed out' in spring redis after only a couple reads?

Tags: spring, junit, redis

I have a simple RedisStringTemplate which is throwing SocketTimeoutExceptions after only a couple reads of one key. I haven't set any timeout in any config, so it is using the default. This is happening in a junit run under SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, if that matters.

If I run just one test case, which does several reads and a couple of updates, it works fine.

But if I run the whole test class, which has a couple test cases which read the value, including some set up/cleanup code, which read and update the value, I get these 'Read timed out'.

To do the read, we simply do

```
myRedisStringTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
```

to update this key, we do

```
myRedisStringTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, valueForKey);
```

In the scenario with the errors, I believe there is only one update on this key, to set the initial value. Then a couple reads on that key before the 'Read timed out' starts, in the @Before before the next test method, where we're trying to clean up data from the previous test.

This is within a Spring application.

Here's the stack trace :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
                ||||||c.i.q.c.MeteredAssignmentsCacheController:73
16:25:32.090|E| java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    com.mycompany.rest.exception.RestException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.mycompany.myclass...
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:710)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at com.mycompany.spring.metrics.MetricsAspect.advice_Timed(MetricsAspect.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:32)
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:643)
    at com.mycompany.myclass...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConverters.toDataAccessException(JedisConverters.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.get(JedisConnection.java:962)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.get(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:264)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations$1.inRedis(DefaultValueOperations.java:45)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations$ValueDeserializingRedisCallback.doInRedis(AbstractOperations.java:50)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.get(DefaultValueOperations.java:42)
```

Comment: Can you add redis configuration, and full stack trace?

Comment: The only configuration we do is to set up RedisTemplates for the 3 different types of objects we're storing. One is a simple String, the others are our classes. But the problem I'm having is with the simple String storage.

Comment: Facing same issue, Did you find any solution on tihs?

Answer (score 0):

From point of view of redis, this is highly unlikely occasion. So you most likely have mistakes in your Spring or Redis configurations.

For example I can assume, that you specified timeout in redis configuration
http://redis.io/topics/clients

> By default recent versions of Redis don't close the
>   connection with the client if the client is idle for many seconds: the
>   connection will remain open forever. However if you don't like this
>   behavior, you can configure a timeout, so that if the client is idle
>   for more than the specified number of seconds, the client connection
>   will be closed.

So if you're using connection pool for Redis in Spring, some of your connections would timeout, at some point, but would still remain in the pool.

Can you check what timeouts you currently have in your Redis configuration?

Comment: I said in the original post that I haven't set any timeout in redis config, so it's using whatever the default value is.

Comment: Redis running localy?